# Why the Execution time for Same SQL Query varies?

Tags: sql-server, database-performance

I am executing a stored procedure on my machine in SSMS and database is located on Server.

The stored procedure works properly, but every time it takes different time to execute even if all parameters are the same. Execution time varies from 1 minutes to 8 minute. I am not able to find reason for this and I am not using any DBCC command in between.

Please share your thoughts on this

Comment: There could be many causes for why this happens. Best chance to get an answer is to share the **actual execution plans from multiple executions**. You can try using [pastetheplan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) for that. Then come back and add those links and more information (like code, parameters, indexes on tables etc.)
 to your question.

Comment: Without the code being run, and the execution plans, we can only guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple possible reasons.

1. Slow disk, too little RAM - other operations load different data to cache
2. Corrupted disk - sometimes read operations delay
3. Heavy CPU usage in your procedure - other processes eat CPU away
4. Locking problems - other operations lock required tables sometimes

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for...